# Apache spark : How deep is the comparison of rows in RDD or DF

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, intersect

I want to understand the behavior of DF.intersect().

so the question came to mind, especially when we have complex Rows having complex fields. (deep tree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are talking about dataframe `intersect` transformation, then, according to the Dataset [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#intersect(other:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BT%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BT%5D) and [source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L2081), the comparison is done directly on the encoded content. Which is as deep as it can possibly go.

> def intersect(other: Dataset[T]): Dataset[T] 
>  Returns a new Dataset
> containing rows only in both this Dataset and another Dataset. This is
> equivalent to INTERSECT in SQL.
>
> Since
> 1.6.0
>
> Note: **Equality checking is performed directly on the encoded
> representation of the data and thus is not affected by a custom `equals`
> function defined on T.**